# JTextArea: Center Alignment

Tags: java, swing, center, jtextarea, center-align

I'm trying to make a calculator program in java, but I'm not sure how to center the text in my JTextArea. I've tried searching google and YouTube, but I don't find anything. Here is my source code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Sect1 extends JTextArea{
    public static final Dimension ss = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    
    public Sect1(){
        this.setBounds(ss.width / 4, ss.height / 5, 100, 100);
        this.setLineWrap(true);
        this.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a JTextArea? Typically a calculator displays the results on a single line which would imply you use a JTextField. A JTextField allows you to center the text horizontally. You can also use a JTextPane which will allow you to center the text horizontally.

Comment: Well it's a table calculator, so the user would type 10 : 20 then 1 : x then the computer would say x = 2

Comment: I would still suggest the input is a JTextField and then you can output the results to a JTextArea. See: [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) for a basic example of using two components.

Comment: Skip centering the text in a JTextArea.  Finish your project and if you have time, come back to centering the text.  Besides, table calculators left justify the output.

Comment: Alright I'll just finish it up.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to consider entering text in a single line with JTextField and center its contents using:

```
setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
```

But if you need something like JTextArea for introducing multiple lines of text, use **JTextPane** or its subclass, JEditorPane which give you more customisation and control over the written text.

For centering text inside a JTextPane:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

StyledDocument documentStyle = textPane.getStyledDocument();
SimpleAttributeSet centerAttribute = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setAlignment(centerAttribute, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
documentStyle.setParagraphAttributes(0, documentStyle.getLength(), centerAttribute, false);
```